# How to replace the html tags with SED?

Tags: unix, sed

i need some help with using sed in unix.
i need to Use the standard Unix command sed to process the input stream and remove all HTML  tags, so that for example:

```
This is <a href="foo.html">my link</a>.
```

will be replaced by

```
This is my link.
```

I tried

```
sed -r 's/
<[^>]*>
//g'
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1848654

Answer (score 0):

In the general case you *cannot* parse HTML with regular expressions.

But, for simple case and assuming that no tag spans more than two lines, you can use:

`sed -e 's/<[^<>]*>//g' -e 's/<[^<>]*$//' -e 's/^[^<>]*>//'`

The first regex finds and deletes tags contained on one line. The second takes care of tags which begin on a line but end on the next. The third deletes the tails of tags which began on the previous line. I a tag can span more than two lines then something more complicated (or a better tool) is needed.

Comment: Fails on `<!-- > -->` or `<img src=x title=">">`.

Comment: @melpomene: Yes, obviously. One cannot partse HTML with regex. I have edited the answer to make it clear.

Comment: my answer suposed to be in 1 part.
sed -r 's/
.....(the answer)
//g'

my answer have to be a regular expression which matches "<a>", "<a href=x>", "</a>" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely bare-bones and unlikely to catch all of the scenarious that HTML will throw at you, but if you are looking to just trim a leading and trailing < and >, then something like this might work:

```
sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

But seriously, I'd use a parser.

Comment: i can use only sed -r .
 It must be a regular expression which matches "<a>", "<a href=x>", "</a>" and so on.